# SDCC missing header file pic16f887.h

Tags: compilation

Trying to compile a c program for a micro controller through `SDCC`

running:

```
sdcc -mpic14 -p16f887 blink.c
```

gives:

```
blink.c:6:27: error: pic/pic16f887.h: No such file or directory
blink.c:12: warning 197: keyword 'at' is deprecated, use '__at' instead
blink.c:12: error 20: Undefined identifier '_CONFIG1'
blink.c:12: error 2: Initializer element is not constant
blink.c:13: warning 197: keyword 'at' is deprecated, use '__at' instead
blink.c:13: error 20: Undefined identifier '_CONFIG2'
blink.c:13: error 2: Initializer element is not constant
blink.c:43: error 20: Undefined identifier 'TRISC'
blink.c:65: error 20: Undefined identifier 'PORTC'
```

Comment: googled found out that in Debian/ ubuntu when installing sdcc from source pic header are missing for 16xxx. the new lead is http://www.warpedlogic.co.uk/node/8

Comment: `/opt/sdcc/src/sdcc-code/sdcc/device/non-free/include/pic14/pic16f887.h`
... non-free subdir of sources... maybe not included in building debianish packages...

Comment: actually installed mplabx on windows and compiler  still complaining about not having header file.  plan to watch youtube videos on compiling on  mplabx maybe it will carry over to sdcc